# Sign Hash with windows Cryptography functions C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cryptography

I am using visual studio 2005 and C++.

Hello, I use a very good function to sign [CryptSignMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). With this I can specify signed attributes, signatory's certificate, unsigned attributes, if is detached and so on.

However, one of the parameters of this function is the "original document", which according to the documentation this creates a hash of the specified content and signs the hash

I wonder if I can create a signature equivalent, using only the hash of the document. I do not have the document, I have only the hash.

I found [CryptSignHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380280%28VS.85%29.aspx), but this function does not allow specify parameters as signed attributes or unsigned attributes and/or signatory's certificate. According to my research, this function seems to return a PKCS#1, where later I should set up a structure of signature PKCS#7. So would be grateful to know if there is any way to make a signature with the hash and if there is a way to create a PKCS#7 structure from PKCS#1 using windows functions. Or Is there any way to sign only the hash, which is as simple as using CryptSignMessage?

**#update 1**

The CryptSignHash does not return PKCS#1. Return a byte array with PKCS#1 padding.
I tried to use [CryptMsgOpenToEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918284.aspx) and [CryptSignMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passing the contents as "NULL" and adding the hash to signed attributes, they calculate the hash of empty.

Is there any way to do this using Windows functions?

Comment: Just a note: You should not sign a document which you have not seen. This might have important legal implications.

Comment: Thanks. This feature will prevent bandwidth consumption.

Comment: If you trust someone (i.e. the person/program/... at the other side of your limited-bandwith channel) that much that you'll sign anything he sends you (whether as hash or as a whole document), you could almost directly give your private key to him. (I would still answer your question, but I know nothing about the Windows Cryptography API, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad idea to sign a hash without calculating the hash yourself. See [Sign a Hash](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2004-May/021010.html), [Generate digest and signature separately](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2011-June/042079.html), and [MFSA 2006-60](http://www.mozilla.org/security/announce/2006/mfsa2006-60.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I realized that these links are about gnupg. I would like to use Windows's Functions.

Comment: @Cobaia: - yes, they are links to other programs/libraries (the topic has been discussed elsewhere). The point is thats its bad to sign a hash which (1) you did not claculate yourself, or (2) you did not calculate at the time of the signing. Very bad karma.